# ar_sendmail - "Could not find RubyGem cyu-ar_mailer" when it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to test emailing on our staging server.  We use ar_sendmail and i'm sure it has worked on this server in the past.  Now though it complains about a missing gem which is actually there:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ar_sendmail start
Starting ar_sendmail: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem cyu-ar_mailer (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/ar_sendmail:18

$ gem list | grep ar_mailer
cyu-ar_mailer (1.4.8.1, 1.4.7)
```

what-the?  Anyone know what might be going wrong here?  I tried reinstalling the gem just in case and get the same error.  This is the content of the file which is blowing up (/usr/local/bin/ar_sendmail)

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/ruby
  2 #
  3 # This file was generated by RubyGems.
  4 #
  5 # The application 'cyu-ar_mailer' is installed as part of a gem, and
  6 # this file is here to facilitate running it.
  7 #
  8 
  9 require 'rubygems'
 10 
 11 version = ">= 0"
 12 
 13 if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
 14   version = $1
 15   ARGV.shift
 16 end
 17 
 18 gem 'cyu-ar_mailer', version
 19 load 'ar_sendmail'
```

grateful for any advice - max

Comment: do you get the same error without sudo?

Comment: @iouri - yes, same thing without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by starting it like so:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ar_sendmail -e staging -d --batch-size 100 --delay 150
```

where 'staging' is the name of my staging environment.  I think that it wasn't getting the right environment before which is why it was blowing up thinking the gem wasn't there.